# Critical section in System.Threading.Timer callback

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, timer, mutex

In my application I have a number of `System.Threading.Timer` instances. There is a posibility that two of them will overlap each other. The problem is that there's a critical section in the callback method. Is it my concern to provide appropriate synchronization or does framework provide a solution?

There were some doubts about question, so I'll make it more clear: I have no synchronization at the moment in the callback.

Comment: When you say "critical section", what *exactly* do you mean?

Comment: To be more specific, there is a connection object in my callback.

Comment: Hard to see the point of this question.  If you have a "critical section" in the callback then you are already providing synchronization.  As required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it my concern to provide appropriate synchronization

If it is critical and it should have mutually exclusive access than yes you need to take care of it yourself.

> does framework provide a solution

Framework does provide multiple tools to do locking and monitor. It depends on your requirement what you need. You need to take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx) to see what framework provides.

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

You also have the option to use [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When two or more threads need to access a shared resource at the same time, the system needs a synchronization mechanism to ensure that only one thread at a time uses the resource. Mutex is a synchronization primitive that grants exclusive access to the shared resource to only one thread. If a thread acquires a mutex, the second thread that wants to acquire that mutex is suspended until the first thread releases the mutex.

Comment: This answers my question. I wasn't sure if Timer callbacks can be called concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You definately have to "concern yourself" with it.  If you choose not to, then you will introduce race conditions to your application and therefore unwanted behaviour.

.NET offers a number of solutions, each of which have pros and cons.  A brief list could include:

- **Locks** - I would say the simplist method.  You would `lock` the shared memory that would be altered on the `callback` method.  This way, only one thread can alter the object at a time.  The downfall of this is if you have multiple threads always waiting for a lock to be released, then what's the point.  The overhead of the lock would probably make everything slower than just using a single thread.
- **Read/Write Locks** - Similar to a `lock`, but now instead of doing a universal lock, you could have multiple threads reading from shared memory and only locking everything out when you require a `write lock`.  This can allow for multiple threads to safely access memory at the same time.
- **TPL (Task Parallel Libary)** - .NET specific.  This most likely would be your most complicated solution, and might require a data structure change.  But I wanted to throw it in here because I think it offers a very strong solution.  A simple explanation behing using TPL, is to only have one thread operate on the shared memory at a time, however don't block other threads while doing so...  So this avoids the problem of having multiple threads messing with your object and causing race conditions, but you also don't tie up several threads.  A good starting point might be to look at the [Data Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) document and see which data structure best fits your needs.

There are several more options, so don't take this as a complete list...  I would push for `TPL` for most cases...

Comment: I know synchronization methods. You must have misunderstood my question, but thank you for your thorough answer.